# Drawing straight line with seaborn using only 2 points

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to know if it is possible to tell my function "seaborn.lineplot" to draw a straight line instead of a line between 2 points. In parameters, I gave just 2 points (2D).

Obviously, I have my equation and I can give all data, but I don't want to. 
I don't find the answer in the documentation : 
https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html

EDIT :

[I have something like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubU3D.jpg)

[I want something like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBee0.jpg)

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smlGt.jpg)

In this code, high and low are 2 python list of list, where element 0 represents the point positions (2) in x and element 0 represents the point positions (2) in y.

Comment: You should give some code samples and output that demonstrate what you're trying now and why it's not working

Comment: It' is unclear what you mean by wanting to draw a straight line instead of a line between two points (which is also a straight line). Do you mean a horizontal line? Or a vertical line? Or that you want it to extend beyond the ends of the two points comprising the line?

Comment: I would like an extension of the line. I have uploaded some images.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes a toy dataset (refer to [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples))

Comment: OK thanks, I will give you more example next time :)